# Set PPT 3D Column Stacked series/legend color from C#

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

I'm creating an XlChartType.xl3DColumnStacked chart and now I want to explicitly set the color of each series.  Everything I've tried so far has failed.  Does somebody have an example they can show me please?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop on the Chart.SeriesCollection and set series.Interior.Color to the desired RGB integer value.

```
            For i = 1 To chart.SeriesCollection.count
            Dim series As Series = chart.SeriesCollection(i)
                series.Interior.Color = newColor
            Next
```

Comment: What's 'newColor'?   I've tried both an actual Color.red type element, and I've also passed in the RGB value as an integer.  Both give me an exception.

Comment: it's an RGB value as an integer. Setting it to 0 should make your column black. Is the sheet / chart protected ? What does the exception say ?

Comment: Invalid parameter.  Nothing is protected as the chart was just generated via code as well.